# EWMA on group / bucket of data

Tags: r, exponential, moving-average

I have a time series vector I need to create a trend off of.

I was trying to get the EMA function in R (through the TTR package - I am loading quantmod, and TTR is required) to run over a group of prices.

Is there a way to create an EMA estimate over a given amount of rows in the vector, so I have one EMA estimate for each bucket? Say I have a bucket size of 10 and I would like to estimate the trend between each bucket, just choosing open and close for the bucket negates a large amount of info, so I would like to have an estimate over the bucket, but with just one output.

Alteratively I tried averaging over the bucket length, but this doesn't produce the desired output.

Example of the vector I am using

```
dput(head(price, 200))
c(137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.1, 137.4, 
137.4, 137.4, 137.4, 137.4, 137.4, 137.1, 137, 137, 137, 137, 
137, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.7, 137, 137, 137, 
137, 136.7, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.5, 136.5, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 137, 137, 137.3, 136.7, 137, 137, 137, 137.1, 137, 137, 
137.1, 137.1, 137, 137, 137.1, 137, 137, 136.8, 137, 137, 136.9, 
136.8, 136.7, 137.1, 137, 137, 137.1, 137, 137.1, 137.1, 136.7, 
136.7, 136.7, 136.7, 136.7, 136.8, 137, 137, 137, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 136.9, 137, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.8, 
136.8, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 137, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136.9, 
136.9, 136.9, 137, 137, 136.9, 137, 137.1, 137.1, 137.1, 137, 
137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.1, 137.1, 136.9, 
136.8, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 137, 136.9, 137, 137, 
137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136.9, 
137.1, 137.1, 137.1, 137.1, 137, 137, 137.1, 137.1, 137.1, 137.1, 
137.1, 137.1, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 
136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9, 136.9)
```

Comment: Do you want to split you price vector in 10 equals intervals and apply EMA to each one?

Comment: Not in 10 equal intervals, but in intervals of length 10 (or any number I choose).

Answer (score 1):

```
bucketsize=10

bucket=rep(1:ceiling(length(price)/bucketsize),each=bucketsize)

aggregate(price,list(bucket),mean)
```